# Generate a new value in Scala AST

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-macros

I'm using APIs to reconstruct the scala AST during compiling.

I want to change an "Apply" AST like

```
a(1)
```

into an "Assign and Return" Block

```
{

val newvalue = a(1)

newvalue

}
```

And here's my code for generating a new value in AST:

```
val newVal : Tree = gen.mkPatDef(Typed(Ident(newTermName("newvalue")), returnType), a)(new FreshNameCreator("newvalue"))(0)
val newSymbol = newVal.symbol.newValue(newTermName("newvalue"), a.pos, 0)
newVal.setSymbol(newSymbol)
newVal.setType(a.tpe)
newVal.symbol.setName(newTermName("newvalue"))
newVal.symbol.setInfo(a.tpe)
```

In the code, "a" is the Apply AST

I do this change after scala compiler phase "packageobjects", the transformation of AST tree can be finished, but it always gets stuck after that. I guess the problem lies in the symbol for the "newvalue", because it works if I use an existing symbol of a existing value, instead of creating a new one by myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Please reedit your question.

Comment: @luoluo Thank you for viewing my question. Can you check whether I've make it clear now? Basically, in the AST tree of a scala program, when I find a function A calls another function B as its return value, I want to first assign the call of B to a new value, and then use this new value as the return value of A. Could you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out! Yet another problem will occur when function call "a" returns "Unit", in this case when I use "newvalue" as return, it report a type mismatch error:

> error: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Can't convert from UNIT to REF(class BoxedUnit) in unit hello.scala at source-/Users/shiyu/Scala/FinalDataFlow/src/print/hello.scala,line-347,offset=13999

But my code below works under other cases. In the code "d" is DefDef AST node of a function definition, "a" is the Apply AST node of the tail function call at the end of "d", and "b" is the right hand side Block of "d".

```
val newVal = ValDef(Modifiers(0), newTermName("newvalue"), d.tpt, treeCopy.Apply(a, a.fun, a.args))
val newSymbol = a.symbol.newValue(newTermName("newvalue"), a.pos, 0) 
newSymbol.owner = d.symbol
newVal.setSymbol(newSymbol)
newVal.symbol.setName(newTermName("newvalue"))
newVal.symbol.setInfo(a.tpe)
newVal.setType(a.tpe)
val newIdent = Ident(newVal.symbol)
newIdent.setType(a.tpe)
treeCopy.DefDef(d, mods, name, tparams, vparamss, tpt, treeCopy.Block(rhs, b.stats ::: List(newVal), newIdent))
```

Comment: Could any body tell me the difference between UNIT and boxedUnit in Scala?